# Java split string and construct a Map

Tags: java, string, hashmap

In my java application, I am using Java8. I have a string representation like below.

```
20232,20221,20222,20223,20224,20225,20226,20227,20228,20229,202210,202211,202212,20231
```

Here, first 4 digits refer to Year and next 2 digits refer to Month.
I want to make a Map where key is YEAR and value as all the months that are available in the string.
i.e; I want something like

```
 2023 -> 1,2
 2022 -> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 (In ascending order)
```

I tried something like this: it gives output as

```
[Key] : 2023 [Value] : 2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1
[Key] : 2022 [Value] : 2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1

public class TestJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String str ="20232,20221,20222,20223,20224,20225,20226,20227,20228,20229,202210,202211,202212,20231";
        String lst[] = selDatesStr.split(",");
        HashMap map = new HashMap();
        StringBuilder stb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i < lst.length; i++) {
            String year = lst[i].substring(0, 4);
            if(!map.isEmpty()) {
                if(map.containsKey(year)) {
                    
                }
            }
                String month = lst[i].substring(4, lst[i].length());
                
                if(stb.toString().length() == 0) {
                    stb = stb.append(month);
                } else {
                    stb = stb.append(","+month);
                }
                
                map.put(year, stb); 
            }
        
        map.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println("[Key] : " + key + " [Value] : " + value));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sidequestion: if this is new code, why use java 8? The current JRE is 19, and the current LTS version is 17.

Answer (score 2):

In this solution, I've split the input string by `,` and using `Arrays.stream` create a `Stream<String>`. Then, I've used `Collectors.groupingBy` to create a map with year as the key and with a *mapping* collector extract the month (as an Integer) and collect them into a `TreeSet` (to collect the months in ascending order).

```
Map<String, Set<Integer>> yearToMonths = Arrays.stream(str.split(","))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.substring(0, 4),
                Collectors.mapping(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.substring(4)),
                        Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new))));
```

With this temporary result, we again stream on the map and by using `Collectors.toMap` build the final map where we take the value (`Set<Integer>`) and join them as a string by `,`.

```
Map<String, String> result = yearToMonths.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue()
                .stream()
                .map(String::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","))));

result.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println("[Key] : " + key + " [Value] : " + value));
```

---

If you are beginner and find it difficult to understand Java streams and Collectors, here it a beginner-friendly approach.

```
Map<String, Set<Integer>> yearToMonths = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();

String lst[] = selDatesStr.split(",");

for (int i = 0; i < lst.length; i++) {
    String year = lst[i].substring(0, 4);
    Integer month = Integer.parseInt(lst[i].substring(4));
    if (!yearToMonths.containsKey(year)) {
        yearToMonths.put(year, new TreeSet<>());
    }
    yearToMonths.get(year)
           .add(month);
}
for (Map.Entry<String, Set<Integer>> entry : yearToMonths.entrySet()) {
    String year = entry.getKey();
    Set<Integer> months = entry.getValue();
    StringJoiner stringJoiner = new StringJoiner(",");
    for (Integer month : months) {
        stringJoiner.add(String.valueOf(month));
    }
    result.put(year, stringJoiner.toString());
}
```

I've used a `StringJoiner` to join the elements of the Set into a String (rather than a `StringBuilder`) as it will be easier to avoid adding a `,` at the end.